# Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException PHPUnit test fails

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

Im testing with PHPUnit and my test fails on a function. But i don't know why.
The function i want to mock:

```
public function subscribe($email)
{
    $message = new SubscribeMessage();
    $message->setEmailaddress($email);
    $message->setLocale(Locale::getDefault());
    $this->getAmqpProducer()->publish($message, 'newsletter-subscribe');
    return true;
}
```

and my Unit test:

```
public function testSubscribeSendsAmqpMessage()
{
    $email = 'email@email.nl';
    $locale = 'nl';

    $this->amqpProducerMock
        ->shouldReceive('publish')
        ->once()
        ->with(

            \Mockery::on(
                function ($message, $routingkey) use (&$publishedMessage) {
                    $publishedMessage = $message;
                    return $routingkey == 'newsletter-subscribe';
                }
            )
        );

    $this->service->subscribe($email, $locale);
}
```

but the test says:

```
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException : No matching handler found for AcsiRabbitMq\Producer\Producer::publish(AcsiNewsletter\RabbitMq\Message\SubscribeMessage, "newsletter-subscribe"). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
```

How can i fix my Unit test? Or how can i refactor my test?

Comment: Did this help you solve your issue?  Just checking so you can accept the answer to help others, or I can adjust my answer if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You Mock the subscribe, not the internal publish.  When you run the test and call ->subscribe, it will attempt to execute the code in the class.  Therefore, it will try to run the subscribe() method, which you appear to have a strange reference to your Mock.

Normally, your test will mock the subscribe, so you can return a value for the assert test, which is hard coded.

You appear to have tried to mock the GetAmqpProducer() object that is in your regular code.  You need to either be able to pass the mock object to be used into your class, or to be able to assign it.

Simplified Example:

```
class Email
{
    private $MsgObject;

    // Constructor Injection
    public __construct(SubscribeMessage $MessageObject)
    {
        $this->MsgObject = $MessageObject;
        ...
    }

    // Setter Injection
    public function SetSubscribeMessage(Subscribe $MessageObject)
    {
        $this->MsgObject = $MessageObject;
    }   

    public function setEmailaddress($email)
    {
        $this->MsgObject->emailAddress = $email;
        ...
    }

    public function setLocale($Locale)
    {
        $this->MsgObject->Locale = $Locale;
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Your class sample above has too many internal objects and dependencies to be tested as such, since the test will actually call these.  You would use Dependency Injection to pass the objects with known state, and have them return properly.

Please note, I am not showing how to do this in Mockery, as I do not use it, but this simple example should help you understand what I am trying to express.

So a simple test might look like:

```
public function testSubscribeMessage()
{
    $email = 'email@email.nl';
    $this->Mock(
        ->shouldReceive('setEmailAddress')
        ->once()
        ->will_return($email)
        );

    $SubscribeMessage = new SubscribeMessage($this->Mock);
    $SetEmail = $SubscribeMessage->setEmailAddress($email);
    $this->assertEquals($email, $SetEmail);
}
```